# Extracting the key from dictionary using get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How do we use get() to get the key instead of value ?

```
namelist = {0:"Ace", 1: "King", 2:"Queen", 3:"Jack", 4:"10",5:"9"}
```

i want to get 2 for queen.

Comment: No downvote, but are you trying to get the inverse dictionary?

Comment: Yes its a inverse dictionary (y)

Comment: Try `{namelist[k]: k for k in namelist}`

Comment: On the other hand you might be happier with a list.

Comment: 'Happier with a list' is rather vague. Could you give the reason why you think in this case a list would be better? Discussion is one of the best ways to learn new patterns! :)

Comment: He implemented a dictionary where all the keys are ascending integers from 0 on. This is what a list does. `["Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10", "9"]` would do the same. Access: `namelist[key]`, position: `namelist.index('value')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate an inverse dictionary like this:

```
inverse_namelist = {v: k for k, v in namelist.items()}
```

Then you can simply use it as a dictionary like you would to get the key.

Comment: Just be careful, if the values are duplicated you will lose keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
>>> namelist = {0:"Ace", 1: "King", 2:"Queen", 3:"Jack", 4:"10",5:"9"}
>>> for i in namelist:
...     if namelist.get(i) == "Queen":
...         print(i)
... 
2
```

Note - It is not meant to be done so, a dictionary is used to access values when you know the keys and not viceversa. In your case it is better to have a `list` datastructure, As in `namelist = ["Ace", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "10","9"}` and you can access `Queen` as `namelist.index("Queen")`

Comment: I never thought that way. I was stuck at that and this can help me a lot :) Cheers (y) (index)

Answer (score 0):

```
def getFromValue(dictionary, choice):
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if value == choice:
            return key

nameDict = {0:"Ace", 1: "King", 2:"Queen", 3:"Jack", 4:"10",5:"9"}

choice="Queen"

print getFromValue(nameDict, choice)
```